# Intelligent subreporting in Crystal Reports?

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

Here's my situation. I've got to report a list of activities for a place chronologically. There are a multitude of different kinds of activities. They do share some data in common (i'll put this in the main report), but I want to have it so that depending on what kind of activity is done, a different subreport shows the details that are unique for each activity. Is this possible?

Comment: For instance, could I have 4 subreports for each main report and suppress 3 of them that have no matches?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you could suppress the subreports using formulae which look at the fields you use to link the main report to the subreports.

Comment: The only problem unsolved with this is that I can't seem to make the suppressed reports whitespace go away.

Not going to use crystal reports now, Microsoft reports is looking a lot nicer so far.